Measuring anistrophy of magnetic oxides
I am analyzing magnetic measurements from oxide samples, taken using a cheap sensor with the following methodology:
Aplication of elipsoidal fit.
The sensor is powered on and stabilized for 10 seconds.
The sample is placed, and magnetic components (


,


,


B
x
​
,B
y
​
,B
z
​
) are recorded for 10 seconds.
The sample is removed, and the process is repeated for different orientations (0°, 90°, 180°, and 270°).
For each orientation, I record the raw and calibrated values of


,


,


B
x
​
,B
y
​
,B
z
​
, as well as the total magnitude of the magnetic field.
I want to assess the magnetic anisotropy of the samples using these measurements. I’ve already:
Calculated the variance-covariance matrix for


,


,


B
x
​
,B
y
​
,B
z
​
and derived the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.
Observed significant differences in eigenvalues across orientations, indicating anisotropic behavior.
However, I’m unsure about:
The best statistical or physical approach to quantify anisotropy with this methodology.
How to link the eigenvalues (or their ratios) to standard measures of magnetic anisotropy (e.g., uniaxial or biaxial indicators).
Whether additional analyses, such as fitting ellipsoidal models or performing directional statistics, would enhance the interpretation.
Are there established techniques or workflows for analyzing anisotropy using rotational magnetic field data? Any recommendations for key references, tools, or methods would be greatly appreciated.

